# Rails "method:delete" DELETE of resource not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, http-delete

I started working with Rails today. I decided to follow the official "Getting Started" document (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) and it all went really well until I hit the "Delete an article section". I followed the tutorial and added an action:

```
def destroy
   @video = Video.find(params[:id])
   @video.destroy

   redirect_to videos_path
end
```

I am rendering the DELETE link with the given method:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', video_path(video), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
```

Unfortunately, that does not work. The destroy controller is never called and the video not deleted. Using the built-in server, I realized that no DELETE but only a GET request actually reaches the server.

I think the problem lies in the way Rails evaluates the link_to function. The rendered links have the form:

```
<a data-confirm="Are you sure?" href="/videos/3"  method="delete">Destroy</a>
```

If however, I change the HTML tag by hand into data-method, it **works perfectly**. Apparently, I need rails to render it the method as data-method .

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Ruby 2.0.0p481 Rails 4.1.6

Comment: That's a pretty weird problem you getting. I am on Ruby 2.0.0p353 and Rails 4.1.6, yet I get the right link where "method" is "data-method". The only catch is that I am using HAML. You mind posting your Gemfile. Just want a peek at it.

Comment: I updated to the latest Ruby (2.1.3), didn't change anything.

Comment: @Touch 
`source 'https://rubygems.org'


gem 'rails', '4.1.6'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
gem 'spring',        group: :development
gem 'devise'`

Answer (score 2):

try changing the link_to to button_to

I also recently faced this issue. delete calls didn't work on link_to.

Comment: Same thing, method="delete" instead of data-method :(

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', video_path(video), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, remote: true %></td>
```

`remote: true` embeds some JavaScript codes in around somewhere in the DOM which handles the `AJAX` calls and `responses`.. This will send a `GET` request with `_method=delete` param which will route to `destroy` method ultimately.